# Cmake Configuring incomplete, error occurred | Box2d / Linux

Tags: cmake, box2d

I am not able to configure cmake.
The issue is as described below about I am unable to make most of it:

```
CMake error at /snap/cmake/936/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake230 (message):Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_INCLUDE_PATH X11_X11_LIB)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/snap/cmake/936/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)

/snap/cmake/936/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindXII.camke:457 (find_package_handle_Standard_args)
extern/glfx/CMakeLists.txt:27 (find package)
```

Below is the error log (CmakeErrorLog):

```
Performing C SOURCE FILE Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/hariton/Box2D/Box2D/Testbed/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_81640/fast && /usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_81640.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_81640.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hariton/Box2D/Box2D/Testbed/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_81640.dir/src.c.o
/usr/bin/cc -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_81640.dir/src.c.o -c /home/hariton/Box2D/Box2D/Testbed/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
Linking C executable cmTC_81640
/snap/cmake/936/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_81640.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc CMakeFiles/cmTC_81640.dir/src.c.o -o cmTC_81640 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_81640.dir/src.c.o: in function `main':
src.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_81640.dir/build.make:99: cmTC_81640] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hariton/Box2D/Box2D/Testbed/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_81640/fast] Error 2


Source file was:
#include <pthread.h>

static void* test_func(void* data)
{
  return data;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
  pthread_detach(thread);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/hariton/Box2D/Box2D/Testbed/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_f6423/fast && /usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_f6423.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_f6423.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hariton/Box2D/Box2D/Testbed/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f6423.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_f6423.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o -c /snap/cmake/936/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_f6423
/snap/cmake/936/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_f6423.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create CMakeFiles/cmTC_f6423.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o -o cmTC_f6423  -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_f6423.dir/build.make:99: cmTC_f6423] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hariton/Box2D/Box2D/Testbed/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_f6423/fast] Error 2
```

The output log is too big and I cannot post it (maybe can post parts of it).

I am positive that I have all needed libraries installed. The issue must lie with the cmake implementation.
What is did is the following [image]
Basically I was at the CMake master file and I wanted to run it at the testbed folder of box2d.

Can anyone help me out please?

If more information is needed let me know

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Please post the text as text. `am positive that i have all needed libraries installed` OK, so then where are X11 libraries and headers installed?

Comment: @KamilCuk, Posted the image for time saving purpose. about the X11 libraries as far as i know they are installed by default.
The output i have for running xdpyinfo in the terminal is: 
xdpyinfo
name of display:    :0.0
version number:    11.0
vendor string:    The X.Org Foundation
vendor release number:    12011000
X.Org version: 1.20.11

Comment: "about the X11 libraries as far as i know they are installed by default." - No, you are wrong. You need to install `libx11-dev` package.

Comment: Hello @Tsyvarev 
The reason that i said X11 lids are installed by default is because i have them without downloading them myself. Please take a look on the below:
apt-file find libX11
libx11-6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
libx11-6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
libx11-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a
libx11-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
l
There are other entries as well but i am not listing them because there is not enough space.

I think the issue lies in the CMakeLists.txt file but so far i am not certain

Comment: So, do you have `libx11-dev` package installed or not? `apt-file` only reports that a file belongs to the package, but it doesn't tell whether the package is installed or not.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you were right. i did not have, specifically  the x11-dev library.
i have installed it and will report back the results

dpkg -l | grep x11-dev
ii  libx11-dev:amd64                      2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.2                    amd64        X11 client-side library (development headers)

Comment: So i run the cmake command again: cmake -S . -B /home/hariton/Box2D/Box2D/Testbed/Build
 
and got the following error:
CMake Error at extern/glfw/CMakeLists.txt:35 (message):
  The RandR headers were not found

I found that log and specifically that part states: # Check for XRandR (modern resolution switching and gamma control)
    if (NOT X11_Xrandr_FOUND)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "The RandR headers were not found")
    endif()

Answer (score 0):

Eventually was able to configure cmake without error

Initially the problem was because the following library was not installed: x11-dev

Then another error came up, as noted in the above comment.
After installing the following xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev the configuration was completed without any errors.

Thank you both for the help!

Comment: I face the same problem, but can't fix it with the steps given here. 

I keep getting

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_LIB)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindX11.cmake:366 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  extern/glfw/CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
```

Would be so kind to share the list of packages you installed?

Comment: Nevermind, a stupid mistake. I was building with  `emmake cmake` for webassembly and tried to build a library that uses `glfw`. That is not supported.